# Error "Assertion Failed: Expected an object as `data` in a call to `push`/`update`" when trying to normalize and push

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my Ember app, I get notifications from a websocket. When the websocket receives a message (encoded as JSON), I want to push it into the store.

Here's my code so far:

```
console.log('About to normalize', data);
var normalizedData = this.store.normalize('message', data);
console.log('About to push', normalizedData);
this.store.push('message', normalizedData);
```

data and normalizedData end up being exactly the same values, which is something like this:

```
{"message":{"id":1,"chatroom":1,"player":1,"content":"A message"}}
```

And calling the push method provokes this error:

```
Error: Assertion Failed: Expected an object as `data` in a call to `push`/`update` for message ,
but was {"message":{"id":1,"chatroom":1,"player":1,"content":"31232132113"}}
```

I don't know what is wrong. When Ember gets a specific message from the server, it receives the same kind of JSON and Ember Data deals well with it. When it comes from a websocket and needs to be pushed, it crashes.

**Update**

I tried to use pushPayload instead like it was proposed in the comments. It still doesn't work. I get those messages:

> "WARNING: Encountered "0" in payload, but no model was found for model name "0" (resolved model name using arkipel@serializer:-rest:.typeForRoot("0"))"
>
> "WARNING: Encountered "0" in payload, but no model was found for model name "1" (resolved model name using arkipel@serializer:-rest:.typeForRoot("1"))"
>
> "WARNING: Encountered "0" in payload, but no model was found for model name "2" (resolved model name using arkipel@serializer:-rest:.typeForRoot("2"))"

It goes up to number 67, then keeps going with words like fmt, camelize, htmlSafe... I'm pretty just data is just a string representing JSON.

Comment: It might be that 'content' is a reserved property in Ember Data, I'm not sure though if this is still the case (they might have changed that).

Comment: @jcbvm Interesting, thank you. I'll check that.

Comment: @jcbvm I get the same error, even after changing content to body.

Comment: Ah ok, can you try to do pushPayload instead of first normalizing and than pushing. So `this.store.pushPayload('message',data)` instead.

Comment: Are you sure data is not an array? From the error messages it looks like data is an array with multiple 'message' objects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70479/discussion-between-jcbvm-and-marc-francois).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After we did some debugging in the chat we found the problem. I'll share the solution here for others.

The websocket was sending messages in string format. So the `data` in the javascript code was a string and not a javascript object (JSON). Ember Data expects us to push a javascript object and not a string.

The solution is to first parse the response from the websocket to a javascript object before pushing it into the store, for example by doing `JSON.parse(data)`.

Comment: Can you explain how you implemented this in your ember app? do you create an adaptor?

Comment: We had a similar problem with pushPayload which does require JSON object. In our case we already had an object, but pushPayload couldn't use it. So we ended up calling stringify and then parse to load our user into store. It looked something like this: `store.pushPayload('user', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({ user: authUser })));`